# How to access property on an object with React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Working with React Native, unable access the `brand` property of my object and of course less `brand.name`.

Does anyone know what might be happening? Thank you

Code:

```
<CardItem bordered style={ styles.cardItem }>
    <Text style={{ padding:20 }} >{this.state.beer.brand.name}</Text>
 </CardItem>
```

**Object:**

[image: object on console]

Comment: Can you post the code for the entire component? Then we can see your `setState` calls

Comment: Usually this happens because render is called before the state has been set. This can happen because setState is asynchronous, and because some asynchronous function (e.g. fetch) is called in order to get data that will be used to set the state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should do conditional check before accessing nested keys directly

Something like

```
  const { beer } = this.state;
 return(
     <div>
         <CardItem bordered style={ styles.cardItem }>
              {beer && beer.brand && <Text style={{ padding:20 }} >{ beer.brand.name}</Text>}
         </CardItem>
     </div>
    )
```